# Generating big and slow reports on a server

Tags: web-applications, architecture, server, webserver, application-server

Hypothetically, how would someone go about implementing big and slow reports on a server?
I'm thinking reports where SQL can't be more optimized and that would take up to 60 seconds or more to generate.
I've thought about having a read copy of the database to not block the incoming queries or some way to have a background process do the work and notify the user when the report is done.
Is there a best way to do something like this?

Comment: are you looking for optimization of sql query or a way to show the user a waiting notice?

Comment: It's an hypothetical scenario I was just thinking. 
The sql query cannot be more optimized and the execution time of the server is exceeded when generating the report

Answer (score 0):

SQL database handles simultaneous requests by [Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175523.aspx) and [Locking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx) and you have not to worry about handling of incoming queries. If you want to note the user that the query is queued, you have to implement user interface as well as Ajax requests and show the status of proccess.

Comment: I might not be following you but locking is why I would want a read copy, so I could be generating the report on that copy while users are updating the real one.
So, going back to the question, what if the Ajax request is stalled by the waiting time of the server?

Comment: The developers of SQL server and Mysql and other databases, have implemented all optimized and mathematical and logical solutions to their database so far. Our simple solutions will not help database to act faster and more reliable. We have just worry about the optimized sql queries not about the logic of query handling in server side.

Comment: In Ajax request you can trace all successful and unsuccessful and also waiting request on server and show the user the proper notice.

Comment: That would just hide away the problem, but you would still sacrifice a lot of valuable resources.

Answer (score 0):

It is very rare that reports have to be near real-time. Therefore, you may discuss with business experts to find out if it's acceptable that the data may be stale for a period of time. If that period of time is long enough then you could pre-generate reports and cache them.

Another approach that would be more flexible and scalable would be to publish events of interest on a messaging infrastructure as they are happening. You could then have an asynchronous subscriber that leverages these events to keep a denormalized version of the report up to date.

For instance, imagine that we must produce a report of the total sales per product per year. If the application publishes a message such as `{ type: 'ProductSold', productId: 1, soldOn: someDate, price: 45.55 }` then you may have an asynchronous subscriber that writes to a table like `YearlyProductSales (year int, product_id uuid, total money)` effectively keeping the report up to date as new sales occur.

Since an event describes something that already happened and was recorded then you also wouldn't have to lock anything while reading data and producing the report would be as simple as `SELECT * FROM YearlyProductSales`.

Answer (score 0):

Many reporting engines support asynchronous reporting.  The exact implementation depends on your tech stack, but, for example, if you are using [Jasper Reports, here is how to run a report asynchronously](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/running-report-asynchronously).  If you are using SQL server, [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2d18ed03-2d23-4567-8465-2ffb31cd998c/asynchronous-call-from-jsp-to-net-web-service-then-to-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices) is how you do it using SSRS.  Most reporting engines have some sort of async execution methods.

Setting up read-only replicas is a tried and true way of relieving database load.  Once again, implementation depends on your tech stack.  The answer above, which is starting down the road toward [data-warehousing techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse), is also worth-while.  A good read about data warehouses/data marts will help you decide how much effort you need to invest here.